# Dealing with strings in C

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, fgets

I'm trying to write a stream editor in C and I'm having a hard time dealing with strings. After reading in the lines of a File, I want to store them locally in an array of Strings. However, when I try to store the variable `temp` into the array of strings `StoredEdits` I get a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. Furthermore, if I uncomment the `char* temp2` variable and save this into my array as a workaround, then the last value read in gets stored for every value in the array.

I assume this has to do with the fact that temp2 is a pointer. I've tried a million things like malloc'ing and free'ing this variable after each iteration, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
      #define MAX_SIZE 100 
      typedef char String[MAX_SIZE];   
          int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
              char** StoredEdits;                                                                                                                                                                    
              int index, numOfEdits;
              FILE *EditFile;                                                                                                                                                                                       
              char* temp;
              //char* temp2;                                                                                                                                                                                            

              StoredEdits = (char**)malloc(MAX_INPUT_SIZE*sizeof(String));                                                                                                                                           

              /*Check to see that edit file is passed in.*/
              if(argc < 2){
                printf("ERROR: Edit File not given\n");
                return(EXIT_FAILURE);
              }

              printf("%s\n",argv[1]);

              if( (EditFile = fopen(argv[1],"r")) != NULL ){
                printf("file opened\n");
                numOfEdits = 0;
                while(fgets(temp, MAX_STRING_SIZE, EditFile) != NULL){
                  printf("%d %s",numOfEdits,temp);
                  //temp2 = temp;                                                                                                                                                                                       
                  StoredEdits[numOfEdits++] = temp;
                  //StoredEdits[numOfEdits++] = temp;
                  printf("Stored successfully\n");
                }

..........

              printf("%d\n",numOfEdits);
              for(index=0;index<numOfEdits;index++){
                printf("%d %s\n",index, StoredEdits[index]);
              }
```

Comment: Please [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize temp to point to valid storage.

```
temp = malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE+1);
```

It looks like you may have intended to do something like this:

```
String temp;
```

using your macro. This would be better as a regular char array. And the common name for this is *buffer*.

```
char buffer[MAX_STRING_SIZE+1];
```

Then, you should store in your array, not `temp` itself, but a new string containing a copy of the contents. There is a POSIX function `strdup` that should be helpful here. Note, `strdup` is not part of the C standard, but it is available in most hosted implementations. Historically, it comes from the BSD branch.

```
StoredEdits[numOfEdits++] = strdup(temp);
```

Let me backpedal a little and say that if you're allocating new storage for `temp` *inside* the loop, then you should skip the `strdup` because, as Jim Balter says, this will leak memory. If you allocate `temp` outside of the loop, then it makes little difference whether you allocate it statically (by declaring a `char []`) or dynamically (with `malloc`).

---

By the way, this line will not buy you much:

```
typedef char String[MAX_SIZE];
```

For why, see the classic Kernighan (the *K* in *K&R*) essay [*Why Pascal is not my favorite Programming Language*](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html).

---

Also note, that my examples above do not check the pointer returned by `malloc`. `malloc` can fail. When `malloc` fails it will return a NULL pointer. If you try to store data through this pointer, Kaboom!

Comment: if you both set `temp` to the result of `malloc` and `strdup` it you'll leak memory. Either use `malloc` and skip the `strdup`, or (better, I think, because it doesn't waste memory), use a buffer on the stack and `strdup` it.

Comment: @JimBalter would it still leak if I free(temp) after each iteration?

Comment: @aensm That would fix the leak, but then `strdup` is largely superfluous. It would have the side-effect of shrinking the storage to exactly fit the string. If you've got a gazillion of them, that might be important.

Answer (score 3):

You're right about your problem being because of pointer semantics. You should use copy the contents of the string from temp.

```
char *cpy = malloc(1 + strlen(temp));
if (cpy)
    strcpy(cpy, temp);
//else handle error
StoredEdits[numOfEdits++] = cpy;
```

Comment: This is tagged C. C++ is a different language and answers in terms of that language are not appropriate.

Comment: Oh, how embarrassing. I did not notice until now. I'll edit my answer then.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to work in C, not C++, so I don't think using that string class is possible. I also tried strcpy, but got segmentation faults there as well.

Comment: FWIW I updated my answer to be more like what I would have done in C.

Comment: +1 I'm actually grateful that you posted about C++ at first. It almost certainly shooed away all the C Ninjas who type faster than I do. :)

Answer (score 0):

Others answered the reason for the error.

But from the program, i see that you tried to allocate a character double array. then you store each  line read from the file into the array.

```
StoredEdits = (char**)malloc(MAX_INPUT_SIZE*sizeof(String));
```

if my assumption is right, then you should pass the array into strcpy like the below.

```
strcpy(StoredEdits[numOfEdits],tmp);
```

when you have a file where each line varies in size, it is better to go array of pointers points to character array.